# Should I secure/hide prime and base numbers for Diffie-Hellman?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, diffie-hellman

As we know DH algorithm based upon 2 large prime numbers, which are used to be called as [prime and base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange)

I am writing app which implements DH key exchange algorithm. From security point of view should I take care for securing prime and base numbers? And what are implications if I wouldn't do that?

Comment: This belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the prime number and base are public values and you don't need take care for the security of that values

That values are the equivalent to a public key in RSA

Comment: And what will happen if I won't take care of prime/base - could it somehow simplify attacker's life?

Comment: prime/base has the aim to be transmitted to anyone (even attackers) for that are "public".

Comment: public is public key - it's clear. I'm not really sure that prime/base are really public...

Comment: You can see that are public in the Wikipedia article, and are the basic data transmitted to start the communication